# How can I remove unique column laravel 5

Tags: laravel, migration

How can I dropUnique the column a_b from z table?

If it would be just column a, we can do this:

```
$table->dropUnique('z_a_unique');
```

I've tried:

```
$table->dropUnique('z_a_b_unique');
```

But obviously it didn't work.
Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`dropUnqiue()` will drop index, not the column. You need to use `dropColumn()` after `dropUnique()`:

```
$table->dropColumn('a_b');
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I just want to drop the unique property from the a_z column, not the column  itself

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer is in the question, sorry guys, it works like this:

```
$table->dropUnique('z_a_b_unique');
```

And solved my problem